Python scrapy: get all URLs in the webpage without duplicate URLs
I want to fetch all URLs in the webpage without duplicate URLs using Python scrapy. I wanted to list only URLs starting with allowed_domains = en.wikipedia.org. In case links has external links, I don't want to scan that external link.
When I use the code below, I get a few duplicate URLs, not sure what to change in the settings.py file.
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.spiders import Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

from scrapy import Item
from scrapy import Field


class UrlItem(Item):
    url = Field()


class WikiSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'wiki'
    allowed_domains = ['en.wikipedia.org']
    start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_url',follow=True),
    )

    def parse_url(self, response):
        item = UrlItem()
        item['url'] = response.url
        return item

Then via terminal I'm running below to save the links into CSV file
scrapy crawl wiki -o wiki.csv -t csv


You can use a dictionary to keep track of the URLs that are already seen.

I suggest using a set to keep track of URLs.
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.spiders import Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

from scrapy import Item
from scrapy import Field


class UrlItem(Item):
    url = Field()


class WikiSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'wiki'
    allowed_domains = ['en.wikipedia.org']
    start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page']

    seen = set()

    rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(),
            callback='parse_url',
            # follow=True
            follow=False
        ),
    )

    def parse_url(self, response):    
        if response.url not in self.seen:
            self.seen.add(response.url)
            item = UrlItem()
            item['url'] = response.url
            yield item

I have set follow=False to limit extent of crawl and ensure that there are no duplicates. Once you are happy that this is doing the right thing then go ahead and make follow=True.
